# Can an actionScript2 app be used inside a AS3 app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, controls, actionscript-2

I've inherited an AS2 app that has a lot of functionality. I need to embed this thing somehow in my AS3 app so I can execute function calls etc and basically control it. Has anyone ever tried something like this? I'm assuming I'll have to URLLoader the AS2 SWF into a MovieClip and take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS3 SWF (AVM2 movie) can load AS2 movies (AVM1 movie) using the `Loader` class, but cannot access the methods/properties of it. The loaded AS2 movie will be of type AVM1Movie (and not MovieClip).

[Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html) page about AVM1Movie

The two movies can communicate with each other using the `LocalConnection` class. See [sending data from avm2 to avm1](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/2007/12/14/sending-data-from-avm2-to-avm1/)

Answer (score 5):

Grant Skinner has a very useful pair of classes that simplify `AS3<->AS2` communications over LocalConnection. We've used it to great success.

http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html